# Create a filtered array from two MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the situation.

I have two table in a DB: `tblcustomfieldsvalues` (for custom fields entry) and `tblclients` (contains client list).

`tblcustomfieldsvalues` has following data structure:

`id` => `10`
`relid` => `13`
`data` => `somedataentry`

`id` => `10`
`relid` => `21`
`data` => `someotherdataentry`

`tblclients` has following data structure:

`id` => `13`
`firstname` => `somename`
`lastname` => `somelastname`

I have this code to create an array of `relids` which have `id` = 10:

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tblcustomfieldsvalues` WHERE `id` = '10'"));

$cids = array();

while ($row = $sql)
{
    array_push($cids, $row['relid']);
}
```

Now that I have user IDs of those who have filled their custom fields with some data in the `$cids` array, how can I get those users details from `tblclients`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your table structure for tblclients?

Comment: since you have not given your tblclients structure, but you have perform a join on cid and id

Comment: Added data structure for `tblclients`

Comment: Thanks for supplying your data structure.  See response -- you just need to use an INNER JOIN.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues t
  INNER JOIN tblclients t2 ON t.relid = t2.id 
WHERE t.ID = 10
```

Good luck!

Comment: @OhhMee -- this code will only get you the client details you asked for.  You will need to update your php code -- this query returns all the user ids and the rest of their user information (not just user ids -- anything in your tblclients matching ID 10 from custom fields).  Make sense?

Comment: @OhhMee -- no problem, glad I could!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tblcustomfieldsvalues` WHERE `id` = '10'"));

$cids = array();

while ($row = $sql)
{
    //array_push($cids, $row['relid']);
    $sql1 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tblclients ` WHERE `id` = '$row['relid']'"));
    while ($row1 = $sql1)
    {
          //echo your output
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
 SELECT * FROM
 tblcustomfieldsvalues cv,tblclients c WHERE
 cv.id = 10 and cv.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table structure of `tblclients` I can't be sure, but it sounds like instead of doing separate queries and looping you could just use a join:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblcustomfieldsvalues
    NATURAL JOIN tblclients
WHERE
    id = 10
```